# C# Is there a way to call function that exist in 2 namespaces and call them depends on parameter?

Tags: c#, api, types, invoke

I made API that downloads data from a shop database and compares it to data in SQL.
However to not mess up things we are testing new things on separate website that connects via different address and use different reference with methods + connectedservice.json.

There are 2 namespaces, A (live) and B (test).
Would like to have simple solution to switch between versions without duplicating code.

Thing i am aiming at is way to pass 3 variables

```
await DDD.Api.Commands.UpdateOrders(client, _auth, _message, "2");
```

where client,auth,message can be from live version or test version

My original code:

Class Application

```
//TestAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient client = new //TestAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient();
//TestAtomstore.message _message = new ProdAtomstore.message();
//TestAtomstore.auth _auth = new ProdAtomstore.auth();

//_auth.login = Settings1.Default.TESTUsername;
//_auth.password = Settings1.Default.TESTPassword;

ProdAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient client = new ProdAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient();
ProdAtomstore.message _message = new ProdAtomstore.message();
ProdAtomstore.auth _auth = new ProdAtomstore.auth();

_auth.login = Settings1.Default.PRODUsername;
_auth.password = Settings1.Default.PRODPassword;

await DDD.Atomstore.Api.Commands.UpdateOrders(client, _auth, _message, "2");
```

Class Commands

```
public static async Task UpdateOrders(
ProdAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient client,
ProdAtomstore.auth _auth,
ProdAtomstore.message _message,
string tmpStr)
{
    string result = await client.GetOrdersAsync(_auth);
    etc...
}
```

What i want to do is to pass a variable which can be ProdAtomstore or TestAtomstore.

```
ProdAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient client = new ProdAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient();
ProdAtomstore.message _message = new ProdAtomstore.message();
ProdAtomstore.auth _auth = new ProdAtomstore.auth();
```

or

```
TestAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient client = new TestAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient();
TestAtomstore.message _message = new ProdAtomstore.message();
TestAtomstore.auth _auth = new ProdAtomstore.auth();
```

I was trying to pass it as a generic type where

```
public static async Task UpdateOrders<C,A,M>(C client, A _auth, M _message, string str) 
where C : ProdAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient, TestAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient
where A : ProdAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient, TestAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient
where M : ProdAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient, TestAtomstore.AtomApiServicePortTypeClient
```

I want `await DDD.Atomstore.Api.Commands.UpdateOrders(client, _auth, _message, "2");` to accept client,auth,message from ProdAtomstore and TestAtomstore.
Maybe this explanation will help a little.

Comment: There's no problem with referencing multiple namespaces, any C# application using classes outside of `System` does this. So what's your problem?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here, as you seem to be referring to A and B as types in some places and namespaces in others. (It doesn't help that you've also got a type parameter called A...)

Comment: If you're trying to replace a live system with a test system, without affecting one then consider inserting another layer, with a fixed interface and use dependency injection, whereby one concrete instance points to the live system and the other points to the test system.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic example of when to use dependency injection and a factory pattern.
For example (pseudo code):

```
interface IDataLayer
{
   List<SomeData> GetData();
}

class DataLayerA :IDataLayer
{
    string authData = "xxxxx"; //auth data specific to this data type
    List<SomeData> GetData()
    { 
       List<SomeData> data = SomeApiWebCall(authData);
       return data
    }
}    
class DataLayerB :IDataLayer
{
    string authData = "yyyyy"; //auth data specific to this data type
    List<SomeData> GetData()
    { 
       List<SomeDifferentData> data =GetFromAnotherWebAPIOne(authData);
       List<SomeMoreData> moreData = GetFromAnotherWebAPITwo(auth);
       List<SomeData> convertedData = ConvertData(data, moreData);
       return convertedData;
    }
}
```

Your main code uses `IDataLayer` variable *not* `DataLayerA` or `DataLayerB`.
You then use a class factory to create your concrete instance of either `DataLayerA` or `DataLayerB` at run time and inject it into your code.

This will mean inserting another layer to remove your current code further away from its data source.